# Receiving state mutation error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In my react/redux application have the following actions

```
export function getSeatingChartConfiguration(team) {
 return function(dispatch) {
  ref.child(team.key).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    dispatch(loadSeatingChart(snapshot.val()));
  });
 };
}

export function saveSeatingChartSection(key, sectionData){
 return function(dispatch) {
  ref.child(key).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
   let data = snapshot.val();
   let sections = data.sections;
   let index = snapshot.val().sections.map( (el) => el.name).indexOf(sectionData.name);
   if(index !== -1) {
    sections[index] = sectionData;
   } else {
    sections.push(sectionData);
   }
   data.sections = sections;
   ref.child(key).update(data, function(error) {
    dispatch(loadSeatingChart(data));
   });
  });
 };
}
```

Here is the reducer

```
export default function seatingChart(state = {}, action) {
 switch(action.type) {

  case actionTypes.LOAD_SEATING_CHART_CONFIGURATION:
   return action.seatingChartConfiguration;

  default:
   return state;
 }
}
```

I am not getting any errors when `getSeatingChartConfiguration()` is called but I have receiving `Error: A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path`seatingChart.sections.2.points`.`What do I need to change in my action or reducer to not mutate the state.

Comment: If the result of snapshot.val is the same object and not a new one, you're mutating it, what happens if you copy the sections?

Comment: I attempted to change the `data` definition to `let data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(snapshot.val()));` and received the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.assign` with initial state to avoid state mutation like below,

```
const initialState = { seatingChartConfiguration: [] }

export default function seatingChart(state = initialState, action) {
 switch(action.type) {

  case actionTypes.LOAD_SEATING_CHART_CONFIGURATION:
   return Object.assign({}, state, { seatingChartConfiguration: action.seatingChartConfiguration });

  default:
   return state;
 }
}
```